# Adding To JQuery's Ajax:Success Function

Tags: jquery

I have made a custom sort of wrapper for the JQuery's Ajax function and everything is working quite nicely but now I want to go a bit further. I want to add a custom bit of code to the Success function that will be automatically called with each Ajax Request but that won't overwrite what is specified in the actual request. It needs to be called in the success since it will be modifying content received from the server.

My custom Ajax Func:

```
 $.adv_ajax = function(options) {
            if (!(options.url)){
                options.url="index.php";
            }
            if (!(options.data_type)){
                options.dataType='json';
            }

var extra_success=function(){
 add_special_fx();
}
                options.success=options.success+extra_success;


            return $.ajax(options);
        }
```

A typical Ajax call using it:

```
    $.adv_ajax({
    url: "user_accounts.php",
                dataType: 'json', 

                success: function(response){
$("#mydiv").html(response);

    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to call custom function only in your wrapper, wrap calling your handler to the another function where you can call as many functions as you need:

```
options.success = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
    options.success(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    extra_success(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
}
```

The only thing that I not sure that it will work if your reassing `options.success` with new function, maybe you will need to create separate `options` object end extedn it with current one.

Comment: Thank you very much with a bit of tweaking that worked perfectly. I ended up just making a new object as I found if I set options.success to equal options.success it would make the browser lock up.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ajaxSuccess() function. It fires after every successful ajax request.

http://jqapi.com/#p=ajaxSuccess

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about that function that looks to be quite handy but I just needed more of a localised solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for jQuery Global AJAX Events: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/. They allow you to add event handlers to all AJAX requests.

### .ajaxSuccess()

> Attach a function to be executed whenever an Ajax request completes
>   successfully. This is an Ajax Event.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/*